# Map returns value as objects instead of string

Tags: apex, visualforce, map

I have an issue regarding the values returned by my Map collection. Below are my code samples and some further explanation to my problem. **Please bear in mind I only provided parts of my code I believe relates to my issue.** I expect the values in my Map collection to be the Account name in form of text (e.g ABC Co) but rather my visualforce renders the values as objects (e.g [a09M0000003W32hIAC, a09M0000003WOcrIAG] ). Could someone kindly point out to me what I may be missing? Thank you.

```
public set<String> siteac;     
public Map<String, list<AccountAssociatedSite__c>> mapToAccount; 
public list<AccountAssociatedSite__c>AccountMapList;

public void acsitez(){
    for(string sitename : siteac){
            System.debug(sitename);
            String stringVar = '%'+sitename+'%';
            AccountMapList = [Select RelatedAccount__r.Name From AccountAssociatedSite__c where RelatedSite__r.Related_Site__c like :stringVar ]; 
            system.debug(accountmaplist);
            mapToAccount.put(sitename,accountmaplist);
            System.debug('keys in the map: ' + mapToAccount.keySet());
            System.debug('list of values in the map : ' + mapToAccount.values());


    }

}

public Map<String, list<AccountAssociatedSite__c>> getAccountsOfSitesAndMaps() {

    return maptoaccount;
    }


<apex:form >
   <apex:pageBlock >
       <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!AccountsOfSitesAndMaps}" var="key">
           <apex:column headerValue="Sites">
                {!key} <!-- display the key Values of map -->
           </apex:column>
           <apex:column headerValue="Accounts">
                {!AccountsOfSitesAndMaps[key]} 
           </apex:column>
      </apex:pageBlockTable>
  </apex:pageBlock>
```

AccountAssociatedSite_*c is a junction object, whereas RelatedAccount*_c and RelatedSite__c are references to the two master-detail objects of the junction object i.e Account object and Sites object.

Comment: What are you putting in the siteac set and what does the debug statement when you debug sitename?

Comment: @rao the siteac is a set of strings (actually urls) and from the debug statements I get the expected strings(urls) for each of the sitename. When I run my query through eclipse, I do get the expected result, the actual account name (e.g Select a.RelatedAccount__r.Name From AccountAssociatedSite__c a)

Comment: Can you try {!AccountsOfSitesAndMaps[key][0].RelatedAccount__r.Name} please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation.** You have created a Map containing lists by site name, your formula in Visualforce {!AccountsOfSitesAndMaps[key]} is resulting in your referencing the list itself for the given site, which as you've found does not make good reading.

**Visualforce Text Conversion.** The default behaviour of Visualforce is to attempt to convert any reference to a textual form, in doing so for list references, it dumps the contents of each item (your AccountAssociatedSite__c records) as a comma delimited value as per your example. This is often not visually appealing (accept for for debug use cases) as you get the square brackets and locale neutral formats for numbers and dates etc. Its better to handle the output of this list further yourself...

**Accessing the Items in the List from Visualforce.** What you need to do is to iterate over the list in your Visualforce page and output each item as you want it shown. Something like this...

```
       <apex:column headerValue="Accounts">
            <apex:repeat value="{!AccountsOfSitesAndMaps[key]}" var="accountAssociatedSite">
                <p>{!accountAssociatedSite.RelatedAccount__r.Name}</p>
            </apex:repeat>
       </apex:column>
```

Comment: thanks Andrew. I just executed your suggestion and it worked! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing the map to have a list of your junction object as the value

```
public Map<String, list<AccountAssociatedSite__c>> mapToAccount;
```

If you want the map to have strings returned you would need to initialize it reflect that.

```
public Map<String, string> mapToAccountName;
```

Its a bit confusing though as you are adding a list of accounts, which would indicate that there are multiple accounts per key, so you would need to determine which Name you would want to use for the value.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I just tried that and came up with an error - Error: projectsitescontrollertrial Compile Error: Incompatible value type LIST<AccountAssociatedSite__c> for MAP<String,LIST<String>>. I'm not so sure if it's possible to do a conversion here. And yes there are multiple accounts per key. One site may be owned by several accounts. Please let me know if you need more clarification. Thanks.

Comment: Thats because you are still trying to add the list of objects to the map that you no winitialized as <string,string>.  you need to adjust the line mapToAccount.put(sitename,accountmaplist); to not put objects into the map, but strings

Comment: thanks for the explanation. will try it out and get back to you.

Comment: Hi sfdc_ninja. thanks for helping out. Andrew's suggestion worked. I really appreciate your effort.